# substitution in every other line

Tags: substitute

how do I search/substitute in every other line.
:s/pattern1/pattern2{2}/g

file looks like

1 pattern1 text
2 pattern1 text
3 pattern1 text
4 pattern1 text

Output file should look like
1 pattern1 text
2 pattern2 text
3 pattern1 text
4 pattern2 text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing I thought of is to just inject a conditional in a `:global` command. Something like this...

```
:g/./ if getcurpos()[1] % 2 == 0 | s/foo/bar/g | endif
```

The "global" command `:g/./` will stop at every line that has at least one character and run the following command.

`getcurpos()` returns a list where the second element is the current line number. We do a modulo operation on that number and if the result is 0 we know we're on an even numbered line. In that case we do the substitution.

If you want this to substitute on odd numbered lines instead change the `==` to `!=`.

**Update:** @D.BenKnoble [identified an optimization](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/substitution-in-every-other-line/17070?noredirect=1#comment29269_17070):

```
:g/foo/ if getcurpos()[1] % 2 == 0 | s//bar/g | endif
```

We put the pattern to be replaced in the global command. That way we don't bother processing lines that wouldn't result in a substitution. As an extra touch we can then do `s//bar` because leaving the pattern empty will do the substitution against the most recently used search expression.

**Update 2:** @ChristianBrabandt notes that `getcurpos()` is relatively new (v7.4.313) and offers [a legacy function for fetching the current line number](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/substitution-in-every-other-line/17070?noredirect=1#comment29272_17070) for those with earlier versions of Vim: replace `getcurpos()[1]` with `line('.')`.

Comment: You can replace the `.` with pattern and then leave it out in `s//bar` if its every other line containing the pattern.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That's a nice optimization. Will note it. Thanks.

Comment: Even better: `:g/pattern1/ if line('.')% 2 == 0 | s//bar/ | endif` Should also work with older Vims.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Noted. Thanks. Do you know offhand when `getcurpos()` was added?

Comment: looks like patch 7.4.313 introduced `getcurpos()`

Comment: This is great but it won't work as expected if you're replacing newlines on every other line. The best I could come up with is a two-step process where you first append a delimiter to the end of each line you want to modify (in my situation I needed to modify every odd line): `:g/$/ if getcurpos()[1] % 2 != 0 | s//^I/g | endif` ... and then replace the delimiter: `:%s/^I\n/^I/g`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative. Let Vim run a `:s` command only on those specific lines:

```
for i in range(2, line('$'),2)| :exe i.'s/pattern1/pattern2/g'|endfor
```

This creates a loop, and iterating over each line and for each even line number executes a `:<nr>s/pattern1/pattern2/g` command, replacing pattern1 by pattern2. If you have `pattern1` in your search register already, you can even further shorten it to `for i in range(2, line('$'),2)| :exe i.'s//pattern2/g'|endfor`

Comment: This is particularly good because it's easy to see how to adapt it for only a specific range. Which is what I needed it for.

Comment: @Len I'd argue that using a range is even easier with the other answer. :) Just put it in front: `:100,$ g/foo/ if ...`.

Comment: @BLayer Good point!